# Expression Engine: Trouble with and embed in a relationship loop

Tags: embed, expressionengine, channel, relationships

I have a channel (products) that has a relationship field (uniforms) in it.  The uniforms channel also has a relationship field in it called fabrics.  My goal is to get the name of the uniform, and a list of fabrics.

**Product Template:**

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" url_title="{segment_2}"}
    {uniforms}
    <p>
        Program: {uniforms:program_name}<br>
        Image: {uniforms:uniform_image}<br>
        {embed="product/product-uniformData" id="{uniforms:entry_id}"}
    </p>
    {/uniforms}
```

I have embedded a template and passed on an entry_id to that template.  I am using the embedded template to get the data of the fabrics.

**product-uniformData Template:**

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="uniforms" entry_id="{embed:id}"}
        <strong>{program_name}</strong>
        {fabrics_used}
            Fabrics:{fabrics_used:product_name}<br>
        {/fabrics_used}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I can't get any data in the product-uniformData template to render out on to the page.
I have tried taking out the embed:id variable, and just manually entering a known good id, but that doesn't help.

If I just render product-uniformData template on it's own, and manually input a valid embed:id, the loop renders data just fine.  It is only when I call it from another template that the data won't render.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" url_title="{segment_2}"}
    <strong>{product_name}</strong><br>
    {uniforms}
        {uniforms:program_name} - 
        {uniforms:fabrics_used}
            {uniforms:fabrics_used:product_name}
        {/uniforms:fabrics_used}<br>
    {/uniforms}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

It posts a wall of error messages(one for each product that does not have a uniform) for the admin:
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: 146

Filename: relationship_parser/Tree_builder.php

Line Number: 536

But other than that it works!